# typesafe rest parameter in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Do we have a way to make the rest parameter typesafe. I am trying following code but it is throwing error,

```
<script>
        function AddN(name, ...numArray:number[]){
        let result = 0;
        numArray.forEach((n) => result += n);
        return result;
      }
      document.write(AddN('abc', 2,33,6));

    </script>
```

Comment: [ES6 does not have static typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407765/is-there-support-for-static-typing-in-ecmascript-6-or-7).

Comment: Do we have a way to write type safe rest parameter using TS and later convert into ES6 OR ES5 ??

Comment: That's the whole point of typescript - when you compile it, you get ES6 (or 5 or 3).